# Binding not showing object property

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wanna show some properties in my HTML. The problem when Angular bind with the property it showing nothing, transparent.
When I debugged, the variable "vm.cancha" received the data from the other controller:

[image]

**Controller:**

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('example.infocancha')
    .controller('InfoCanchaController', InfoCanchaController);

InfoCanchaController.$inject = ['$stateParams'];

function InfoCanchaController($stateParams) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.cancha = [];
    vm.obtenerInformacionCancha, obtenerInformacionCancha;

    inicializar();

    function inicializar() {
        obtenerInformacionCancha();

    }

    //funcion para obtener la cancha seleccionada
    function obtenerInformacionCancha() {
        vm.cancha =  angular.fromJson($stateParams.cancha);
        debugger;
    }
}
})();
```

**View:**

```
<ion-view view-title="{{cancha.nroCancha}}">
<ion-content>

    <h3 class="content-horizontal-padding">{{cancha.descripcion}}</h3>
    <div class="list card">
        <a class="item item-icon-left">
            <i class="icon ion-email"></i>
            {{cancha.descripcion}}
        </a>

    </div>

</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Also in my example module I have this:

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('example.infocancha', [
        'ionic',
        'ngCordova',
        'example.comun'
    ])
    .config(function($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('app.example', {
                url: '/example/examplecancha/:cancha',
                views: {
                    'menuContent': {
                        templateUrl: 'scripts/example/examplecancha/example.html',
                        controller: 'InfoCanchaController as vm'
                    }
                }
            });
    });
})();
```

**Could you tell me Why the binding not showing nothing?** 
Thanks!

Comment: you have used controllerAs syntax, check that?  InfoCanchaController as ct. and use ct.cancha.descripcion

Comment: Yes, with this solutions works, but in the others view I had never put that. i wanna know why in the others view works without that

Comment: so in other section you must be using $scope. right?

Comment: May be is because in the others view I use ng-repeat and I don't have to use "as", do I?

Comment: no actually no relation between controllerAs and ng-repeat

Comment: in other view you must not be using this. you are injecting $scope in controller and binding data to it. check below answer it will give idea about controllerAs syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
You have used controllerAs syntax. 

ng-controller = "InfoCanchaController as ct" 
// when you use controllerAs syntax, you are doing $scope.ct = vm = this;

{{ct.cancha.descripcion}}

//when you are injecting $scope in controller, you are attaching data to it directly. 
//In this case it will work as, you are doing $scope.cancha.descripcion = something. 
{{cancha.descripcion}}
```